# Need the logic in SQL to get the relevant records related to the cumulative sum

Tags: sql, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

Hi I am using the the following query which gives me the cumulative sum for each date :

```
select date_in, 
       sum(INFLIGHT_PRODUCT_WISE)
           over (order by date_in 
                 ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
           INFLIGHT_PRODUCT_WISE 
from
(select 
 date_in,count(*)INFLIGHT_PRODUCT_WISE from items)
```

This is the output:

```
Date_in    Inflight Product Wise (cumulative sum)
09-AUG-15  269
08-AUG-15  259 
07-AUG-15  249 
06-AUG-15  239 
05-AUG-15  229
```

When he clicks on 269 he should get all the records for 269 order numbers ,when he clicks on 259 he should get all 259 order numbers and so on.

I Know how the drill down is done in oracle apex.

I just need the SQL query to pull all the related records pertaining to the cumulative sum.

For example- I need to get order number and product name for a cumulative sum of a particular date how do I do that

```
select order_number,product_name from items-- for 259,269 records and so on
```

How is it done?

Comment: Your drill-in step should pass the date associated with the number and you  can do this `WHERE date_in <= '08-AUG-15'`

Comment: I have passed the date but it  is giving records only for the particular day.Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @Bulat `'08-AUG-15'` is NOT a DATE, it is a string. Not a good suggestion. You are trying to compare a date with a string. Always use **TO_DATE** to convert a string into date.

Comment: @LalitKumarB that was a piece of pseudo code, obviously date will be in a variable

Comment: @Bulat What variable? Variables are declared in PLSQL and not in SQL. OP wants to fetch the rows using SQL.

Comment: Can you really click on a number in SQL?

Comment: Hi All,just to clear the air,this is related to oracle apex.. It would be helpful if some on can provide solution:(  ...@Bulat... i tried the logic you gave ,but that is giving only the record for particular day not the cumulative one's

Comment: When you used the @Bulat suggestion did you added on the filter the `<=` or just `=` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Bulat suggested, it appears that you just want

```
SELECT *
  FROM INFLIGHT_PRODUCT_WISE 
 WHERE date_in <= to_date( :p123_your_date, 'DD-MON-RR' )
```

assuming that `:p123_your_date` is a page item that has been populated with the string "08-AUG-15" when you click on the link in the summary report.